# 0V LDO Adjustable Regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, linear

I'm currently researching LDO adjustable regulators to make an adjustable supply that runs from 5V. I want my supply to be capable of supplying down to 0V.

I've found the [LT3083](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3083fa.pdf), which can adjust down to 0V, however has a 310mV drop out voltage. I would prefer to have a smaller drop out voltage than this. Does anyone know of a similar regulator that meets my 0V requirement, but has a smaller drop out voltage? I am seeking a smaller drop out voltage so that my supply's upper range will be closer to 5V.

Thanks

Comment: I'm planning to run off ~5V from a USB port.

Comment: What are your requirements for current?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LT3083 is a good device and your limitations on drop-out can be improved by considering the following: -

[image]

As can be seen, the drop-out at 3A load is just a bit over 300mV but at 1.5A it is about 170mV. Given that devices can be paralleled (diagram on right), maybe you should reconsider this device. Also note the larger words at the bottom - to truly get down to 0V you will need to generate a small negative voltage that is still "removing" 1mA from the device.